# Android: Remove seperator color in Reflection Drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I just want to make a mirror reflection for my logo image. So I used the following code.
[image]  [image]

```
public Bitmap applyReflection(Drawable drawable) {
            Bitmap originalImage = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
            final int reflectionGap = -4;
            int width = originalImage.getWidth();
            int height = originalImage.getHeight();          
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.preScale(1, -1);
            Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, width, height/2, matrix, false);          
            Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, (height + height/2), Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
            canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
            Paint defaultPaint = new Paint();
            canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, defaultPaint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,0, height + reflectionGap, null);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0,

                    bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
            //paint.setShader(shader);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
            canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);

            return bitmapWithReflection;
        }
```

I just want to remove the black line separator.
Please provide me the best way to do this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the mistake.  I thought `final int reflectionGap = -4;` will reduce the gap. But I have to put `final int reflectionGap = 0;` After this the seperator line is removed